# ElasticSearch failed to load plugins (License Module)

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to load ElasticSearch plugins with the offline instructions but it looks like I am getting a permissions error even when I open up permissions to the files completely and running as root! I've removed and reinstalled as well but this error is consistent.

```
[root@ip-10-94-146-130 bin]# ./plugin install file:///home/jmblnvr/shield/license-2.1.0.zip
-> Installing from file:/home/jmblnvr/shield/license-2.1.0.zip...
Trying file:/home/jmblnvr/shield/license-2.1.0.zip ...
Downloading .DONE
Verifying file:/home/jmblnvr/shield/license-2.1.0.zip checksums if available ...
NOTE: Unable to verify checksum for downloaded plugin (unable to find .sha1 or .md5 file to verify)
Installed license into /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/license
[root@ip-10-94-146-130 bin]# service elasticsearch restart
Stopping elasticsearch:                                    [FAILED]
Starting elasticsearch: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize plugins
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/license/plugin-descriptor.properties
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginInfo.readFromProperties(PluginInfo.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.getPluginBundles(PluginsService.java:302)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:148)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:129)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:145)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:285)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Refer to the log for complete error details.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

From /var/log:

```
[root@ip-10-94-146-130 elasticsearch]# cat elasticsearch.log
[2015-12-15 11:44:24,525][INFO ][node                     ] [Valtorr] stopping ...
[2015-12-15 11:44:24,639][INFO ][node                     ] [Valtorr] stopped
[2015-12-15 11:44:24,641][INFO ][node                     ] [Valtorr] closing ...
[2015-12-15 11:44:24,647][INFO ][node                     ] [Valtorr] closed
[2015-12-15 11:44:26,097][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to install syscall filter: seccomp unavailable: CONFIG_SECCOMP not compiled into kernel, CONFIG_SECCOMP and CONFIG_SECCOMP_FILTER are needed
[2015-12-15 11:44:26,314][INFO ][node                     ] [Agon] version[2.1.0], pid[21703], build[72cd1f1/2015-11-18T22:40:03Z]
[2015-12-15 11:44:26,314][INFO ][node                     ] [Agon] initializing ...
[2015-12-15 11:44:26,318][ERROR][bootstrap                ] Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to initialize plugins
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:111)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:148)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:129)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:145)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:285)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/license/plugin-descriptor.properties
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginInfo.readFromProperties(PluginInfo.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.getPluginBundles(PluginsService.java:302)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:108)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Can you also share the logs from the elasticsearch log?

Comment: Added additional details.

Comment: Can you check if you're suffering from the [issue described here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11016)

Comment: Thats exactly the issue thanks! I am wondering that is logged back in May and claiming to be fixed but I downloaded the most recent version of Elastic and it is not.

Comment: Maybe add some comment in that issue?

Comment: Thanks just put a comment in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same sort of exception but after installing and while loading **x-pack** plugin on Elasticsearch 5.2.1:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/x-pack/plugin-descriptor.properties
```

In my case, I started by adding *elasticsearch* user to the root group:

```
usermod -aG root elasticsearch
```

Afterwards, it was only necessary to modify the ownership of the *plugins* folder:

```
chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Val, simple solution is after installing plugins you need to quickly change ownership/groups if you are using the RPM install of Elastic:

```
chown -R root:elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch
```